# If the Universe reaches the state of heat death scenario, could it produce a new Big Bang?

Tags: universe

So in heat death of the Universe time stops, matter is degraded, only quantum vacuum remains and the universe no longer expands?

Aren't those conditions similar to what physicists say about the quantum field from which the Big Bang happened?

So is there possibility that the current Big Bang before 14 billion years happened "after" an already heat death state of previous instance of the Universe?

Or quantum fluctuations can't happen in such scenario and the Universe will remain dead for an eternity.

Comment: *and the universe no longer expands* - assuming dark energy is what we think it is the universe will continue expanding forever. What you describe is basically Penrose's idea of [conformal cyclic cosmology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology). You might want to read up on this and maybe post a more specific question.

Comment: *Aren't those conditions similar to what physicists say about the quantum field from which the Big Bang happened?* No. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5150/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dark age of universe when all fusion process ceases?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74041/)